# How to create a long matrix from one pandas column

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a matrix based on one index column in a pandas data frame. I've laid out a description below of what I'm trying to accomplish. I thought there would be an easy transpose function in Pandas.

This is what I've tried but doesn't yield what I want:

```
df = pd.read_csv('locations.csv')
df.drop(['Country'],axis=1, inplace=True)

df.home.values


pdf = pd.DataFrame(index=df.home.values, 
columns=df.home.values, 
                 data=(df.home.values == 
 df.home.values[:,None]).astype(int))


print(pdf)
```

This results in:

```
       Texas Maine Mass
Texas 
Maine
Mass
```

This is what my starting dataframe looks like:

```
df:
Home          lat lon 
Texas         29  30
Maine         43  73
Mass          42  69
```

This is what I am trying to end up with:

```
 df2:
 Home   lat  lon   Host   lat2 lon2 
 Texas  29   30   Maine   43  73   
 Texas  29   30   Mass    42  69            
 Maine  43  73    Mass    42  69      
 Maine  43  73    Texas   29  30         
 Mass   42  69    Maine   43  73  
 Mass   42  69    Texas   29  30
```

I've looked into numpy arrays but they seem to generate matrices in columns where as I am trying to create it in long form. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was not considered a matrix but instead considered a     permutation

```
permutation
```

I solved my problem by using a mix of permutations and .merge after to get the extra columns I needed.

```
from itertools import permutations
file4 = 'your_data.xls'
df30 = pd.read_excel(file4)

dfp=pd.DataFrame(df30['locations'])
dft = dfp.from_records(permutations(dfp['locations'], 2), columns=['home','host'])
```